# How do I change the numbering of the list of tables and list of figures?

Tags: table-of-contents

My main document looks as follows, where I include other tex-files (here I have only included two files as an example. They are called "chapter2_test" and an appendix called "chapter2_appendix":

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[font=normalsize]{caption}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{eqnarray} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}  % für threeparttaable
\usepackage{graphicx,textcomp,booktabs,} % für threeparttaable
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
%\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\newenvironment{myitemize}{\begin{itemize}\itemsep0pt}{\end{itemize}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Make List of Figures/Tables behave properly (horizontal spacing)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
     \renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{5.0em}}
     \renewcommand*\l@table{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{5.0em}}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Define Headers 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\textsc{Chapter} \thechapter}
\fancyhead[LE]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\begin{document}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Table of Contents/Figures/Tables etc.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\cleardoublepage
\setstretch{1.15}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setstretch{1.5}
    \pagestyle{fancy}


    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Chapter                 %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \chapter{Name of Chapter}
        \input{\string"../Documents/Texfiles/chapter2_test.tex\string"}     
        \setcounter{section}{0}
        \setcounter{figure}{0}
        \setcounter{table}{0}
        \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\Alph{section}}
        \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
        \renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection.\arabic{table}}
        \newpage
        \input{\string"../Documents/Texfiles/chapter2_appendix\string"}
        \cleardoublepage
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\end{document}
```

The first document ("chapter2_test") I include looks like this:

```
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}
Some text.

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\caption{My Figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{\string"../Documents/Data/my_figure\string"}
\label{fig:my_figure}
\end{figure}

In this sentence I refer to figure\ref{fig:my_figure}.

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\caption{My Table}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{1}{lrrrrr}}
\toprule
Variable  &   &   Obs.   &  Mean&        Std. Dev.&           Min&  Max\\
\midrule
Var a   & overall &    761&       7.09&       2.27&          0.50&  12.00\\
        & between &       &           &       1.56&          2.44&  10.55\\
        & within &        &           &       1.66&          1.66&  10.29\\
Var b   & overall      & 747&  7.58&    1.47&             4.19&   11.41\\
        & between        &    &      &    1.36&             5.28&   10.39 \\
        & within         &    &      &    0.54&             6.17&    9.46\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:my_table}
\end{center}
\end{table}

In this sentence I refer to table \ref{tab:my_table}.
```

The second document ("chapter2_appendix") looks like this:

```
\section{Appendix}

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\caption{My appendix table}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{1}{lrrrrr}}
\toprule
Variable  &   &   Obs.   &  Mean&        Std. Dev.&           Min&  Max\\
\midrule
Var a   & overall &    761&       7.09&       2.27&          0.50&  12.00\\
        & between &       &           &       1.56&          2.44&  10.55\\
        & within &        &           &       1.66&          1.66&  10.29\\
Var b   & overall      & 747&  7.58&    1.47&             4.19&   11.41\\
        & between        &    &      &    1.36&             5.28&   10.39 \\
        & within         &    &      &    0.54&             6.17&    9.46\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

The output I get is the follwing:

> List of Figures
>
> 1.1figure My Figure . . . . . . . . 2

and for the list of tables:

> List of Tables
>
> 1.1table My table . . . . . . . . . . 2
>
> 1.A1table My appendix table. .  . . . 3

Directly after the numeration the words "figure" and "table". What I would like to have is only the numbering of tables and figures and then the name of the figure/table, like that:

> List of Figures
>
> 1.1 My Figure . . . . . . . . 2
>
> List of Tables
>
> 1.1 My table . . . . . . . . . . 2
>
> 1.A1 My appendix table. .  . . . 3

Does anybody know how I can achieve that or change the style of appearance? What may be wrong in my code? Because I think using "\listoffigures" would normally create this style as a default and I do not understand why "figure" and "table" is added directly after the numbers of figures/tables in the list of figures/tables.

Thank you in advance for any help or comments!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) If I take the code fragments from your question and build a small test document out of them, I unfortunately can not reproduce the issue you describe. Instead I get the following output:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q7lm.png  Therefore please add a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get.

Comment: Completely unrelated to the issue but you might want to use `\centering` instead of the `center` environment for your table as well. (The latter adds some additional white space that might be undesired.) Also, you can replace `\begin{tabular}{l*{1}{rrr}}` with `\begin{tabular}{lrrr}` or `\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{r}}`. Please also check your preamble and remove packages that you load more than once (e.g. `amssymb`, `caption`, ...)

Comment: Like @leandriis, I am also unable to reproduce the issue you're looking to fix, using solely the information you've provided so far.

Comment: @STS: Thanks for updating your example. Unfortunately, I still can not reproduce the issue you describe. The output I get with your updated example is still the same as [before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506441/how-do-i-change-the-numbering-of-the-list-of-tables-and-list-of-figures?noredirect=1#comment1279492_506441)

Comment: BTW, you loaded the caption package twice.  Something (titling?) has modified \l@figure and \l@table, but i don't see it in your code.